# cors issue with Outlook Add-In

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am writing an Outlook Add-in and I am trying to make a fetch request to Jira. However, I am running into what I think is a CORS issue and I'm not sure how to get around it.

The error message says:

> "[blocked] The page at `https://localhost:3000/index.html?_host_Info=Outlook$Mac$16.02$en-US` was not allowed to display insecure content from `http://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/myself`."

Is there any way to make a fetch request from an Outlook Add-in to get around CORS?

My add-in is just a react based front-end app and the fetch request requires basic authentication which works fine in postman (which of course is outside the browser but outlook add-ins run in a browser component).

Comment: The error says you are trying to access insecure location "http://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/myself". All locations must be secure (*https://*) for Office add-in to make the call. Set up SSL cert for your rest service.

Comment: Thanks Slava, good catch. I was making changes to the code and removed the s from the https of the url. when I add the s back in I get a straight up cors err: Fetch API cannot load https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/myself. Origin https://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. But as I said, I am making a fetch request to the Jira Rest API so I cannot make any changes to the server.

Comment: OK, now the error is CORS. This is up to server to allow and deny CORS requests. Are you in control of the server? Can you change something to allow certain URLs to make CORS requests? If not, you should look for solution when you create your own service which will allow the requests from your add-in and from this service call server-to-server to get the info from original rest point.

Comment: I will look into OAuth with the Jira Rest API and failing that I guess I will have to create a proxy server as you suggest.

Answer (score 5):

When making calls outside the domain your add-in is hosted in, you need to specify those domains in your add-in's manifest:

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>http://mysite.atlassian.net/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://mysite.atlassian.net/</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I will look into this as well

Comment: Having the same issue, but still getting the same error even after adding the domain to the manifest:

  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>http://localhost:8080/</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>

Comment: You need to specify https://. From what I've read and seen http:// is not allowed.