# How to allow cross-origin access for Outlook Web Add-In

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I developed a Outlook Web Add-in using Visual Studio 2017, and so far all my testing is based on hosting the Add-in from localhost, and I had no issues with that, everything worked fine. Now, I moved my Add-in to a shared folder on my Sharepoint server, so that others can test my Add-in.

Within my manifest file, I changed the line which defines the URL of my function file to point to where it is hosted:

```
<FunctionFile resid="FunctionFile.Url" />
```

I also added in a line under

```
<AppDomain>https://<My URL Domain></AppDomain>
```

The image of my add-in icon loads find, however when I click on my add-in icon from my OWA page, I get the following error:

SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'https://' failed to allow a cross-origin document resource at 'ms-appx-web:///assets/errorpages/forbidframingedge.htm#https:///Functions/FunctionFile.html?et='.

Is there any way to allow my add-in to run? I'm currently doing my testing on the Edge Browser.

Thanks!

Update:

Here's my function file html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
   <title></title>
  <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
 <script src="../Scripts/Office/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<script src="../Scripts/Office/1/office.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<script src="FunctionFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- NOTE: The body is empty on purpose. Since this is invoked via a button, there is no UI to render. -->
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hi does your javascript in function file make an fetch or a get request? Please look at this and let me know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687805/cors-issue-with-outlook-add-in

Comment: Hi Add-ins Team, I'm not sure what you mean by that... I've include what I have inside my Functions.html page. I suspect that the browser is blocking even at this point... Could it be a restriction with my Browser security settings instead? Is referencing a page with a different domain name even allowed for Web Add-ins? Thanks!

Comment: When your add-in is making calls outside the domain the add-in is hosted in, you need to specify those domains in your add-in's manifest:

    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>ExternalDomain</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>

Comment: I did do that in my manifest file. Please take a look at the attached.

Comment: Kelvin I'm unable to repro the error, try using a different browser and please share the results.

Comment: Maybe it's not the add-in itself but a browser setting. Could there be anything that is preventing the Add-in from accessing a different domain name? Some security setting or group policy you can think of?

Comment: There is nothing that would prevent the add-in from loading as long as the domain is mentioned correctly in the manifest. Also, please make sure your function file is accessible by copy / pasting the link in the browser directly.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the error message. forbidframingedge.htm seems to indicate that the actual error is that Edge browser is preventing the loading of my html page in an iFrame. To be clear, I'm using my add-in within my organisation intranet. My add-in is hosted on another domain within the intranet.

Comment: Yes, please have a look at similar issue here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860020/sec7117-error-when-trying-to-load-a-javascript-file-in-ms-edge ). This might help.

Comment: I tried what was suggested but still didn't work. Did you try hosting the add-in in a SharePoint folder when you were trying to reproduce the error? Thanks.